# How do I wait for firebase auth to load while using redux toolkit in reactJS?

Tags: reactjs, redux, firebase-authentication, redux-toolkit

I am using firebase authentication system in my ReactJs app along with Redux toolkit, for regular redux, I am aware you can use the middleware function **firebaseIsAuthReady**, how do I use such function to check if auth is loaded before rendering my app using Redux toolkit?

thanks a lot for helping.